# Fragment not calling onDestroyView while parent layout removed

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have been stuck with a very strange problem with layouts & fragments.

I have been assigned with fixing an app that has really poor logic & design. It has single activity & all layout changes are done by simply removing content on wrapper (LinearLayout) and adding views to it.

I have been trying to inflate layout with < fragment > inside. And it works just fine. But when I change wrapper content (removeAllViews()) with different content and then try to reinflate layout with fragment again I get exception with:

`12-18 18:28:36.711: E/AndroidRuntime(11192): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #7: Duplicate id 0x7f07014d, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.test.fragments.SearchTabhostFragment`

While I remove parent layout (wrapper) - Fragment is not executing any of the lifecycle functions (onPause, onStop, onDestroyView etc).

Inflating & reinflating later on:

        `LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search, wrapper);`

Destroying:

            `if (wrapper.getChildCount() > 0) {
                wrapper.startAnimation(out);
                wrapper.removeAllViews();
            }`

Search XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.test.fragments.SearchTabhostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any idea what I might do to clear it from FragmentManager? Is there an event I might use on layout to find out it is being removed?

Comment: try  this `view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search, wrapper,false);`

Comment: Unfortunately - it will not render layout at all when using false. Thanks for trying, Panther :)

Comment: whats the use of `return view` there?? i assume that the returned view is added to the desired place, since `view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search, wrapper)` will automatically add the inflated view to the `wrapper`

Comment: for the error i guess the `wrapper.removeAllViews()` did not remove the views, this is the only case the duplicate id comes into picture.

Comment: Actually they are removed, but FragmentManager probably holds the fragment (my guess). return view; is misleading - removing

Comment: `Fragment is not executing any of the lifecycle functions` because the removeallViews wont consider if its a fragment or not, it just removes the views. You should use `FragmentManger` to handle this adding and removing. Replace `Fragment` with `FrameLayout` and let the `FragmentManager` handle the adding and removing part, then urs should work as expected

Comment: Thank you @Panther. I have just changed to FrameLayout and used FragmentManager instead of Fragment tag & everything worked like a chark. Please answer this question so I can give proper credis to you answer :)

Comment: credits not needed :-/